# cannot see Theme.Material or Android L's things

Tags: java, android

when i create values-v21 for android L' styles but when i cntrl+space for search there isn't any android L library.I checked android sdk manager,everything updated. and i'm using these library in build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 20
buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "......."
    minSdkVersion 13
    targetSdkVersion 20
    versionCode 3
    versionName "1.1"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile files('libs/commons-net-3.3-sources.jar')
compile files('libs/commons-net-3.3.jar')
compile files('libs/commons-net-examples-3.3.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.2.08'
compile 'com.github.mrengineer13:snackbar:0.4.0'
}
android {
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
}
 }
```

Comment: I dont see anywhere, where you reference the L preview

Comment: reference ? so where should i add reference L preview ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you do not reference android L anywhere

your gradle should have these in it

```
compileSdkVersion 'android-L'

minSdkVersion 'L'
targetSdkVersion 'L'
```

Comment: i have to use minSdkVersion 'L' ?

Comment: yes because it is only a preview and you cannot release it to the playstore with it